# Proper syntax for DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

Can I solve an ODE like `xy dy = x^2 dx` using `DSolve` or it should be in the following form  `y'[x] == x^2/(x*y[x])`?

Comment: It should be in the second form.

Comment: Look `DSolve` in the documentation; look at both the expected syntax and the examples.  This should be the first thing you do.

Comment: I have seen that it requires the second form, I just thought if there might be another way to enter it.

Comment: You could also write it as `x y[x] y'[x] == x^2`  Note that square brackets cannot be used as parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to input ODE's in that form: $x y dy = x^2 dx$ using `DSolve`, but it's a bit clunky. First decide that one variable is the dependent variable, for example `y[x]`, and then use the total derivative function `Dt`:

```
sol = DSolve[x y[x] Dt[y[x]] == x^2 Dt[x], y, x]
```

This will generate a solution equivalent to moving the $dx$ term over to the left hand side and executing:

```
sol2 = DSolve[x y[x] y'[x] == x^2, y, x]
```

`sol == sol2` will output True.

It is generally preferable to use `y'[x]` as the notation, but `DSolve` can often interpret free floating differential terms like $dx$ if you specify them with `Dt`.